# I need to pull just the year from a field

Tags: t-sql, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have a date field (work_date) that I just need the 4 digit year from and be in number form. the field looks like this 2020-04-28 00:00:00.000 I just need the 2020 from it.

In sql studio this works,
       select left((convert(varchar(4),[Work_Date],112)),4)
but in crystal reports it say missing ( by convert

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) A quick Google search would have turned up the `Left()` function...

Comment: @Ryan Left is a string not a date function.

Comment: A quick DuckDuckGo (say no to the NSA!) search would have found `Year()` and `DatePart()`.

Comment: @Blam Yes, I know. Saying "the field looks like" makes it sound like it's stored in that exact format, which would make it a string. Regardless, a single function will do the job whether string or date.

Comment: @Ryan "Have a date field".  Left 4 of a date field does not return the year.

Comment: @Blam Semantics. You could have a string representing a date and it would not be be unheard of to refer to it as "a date field". I'm well aware that `Left()` does not work on a Date data type.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Year({table.field})
```

Or this:

```
DatePart('yyyy',{table.field})
```

Answer (score 0):

DatePart yyyy

[DATEPART (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

No need to use any formula, just right click the report field and format it, click customize and get the output you desire, its just the same as you format in excel